# Using RESX with Windows Phone 7 in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, resx

I am currently making a basic Windows Phone 7 application for fun, and I am trying to store string (currently only those) values in a RESX file rather than embedding them all within the XAML files directly, or even adding code to manually insert the values.

In WPF, to use the property from the RESX file, you simply map the namespace that contains the RESX:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Namespace.To.Your.Resx;assembly=SuppliedIfSeparate"
```

and then use it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.AppTitle}" />
```

But, I tried, and I've read that `x:Static` is simply not supported by Silverlight, and by extension, not supported in WP7 ([It appears that they have provided the means, but not direct access to `x:Static`](http://slouge.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/silverlight-x-static-markupextension-like-wpf/) (French) in Silverlight 5/Mango).

I found [this post](http://shineasilverlight.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/accessing-members-in-app-as-a-xaml-resource/) describing an "`AppConverter`" class that is manually created to leverage similar functionality and it is currently what I am doing. The gist of the post is to create a resource within your XAML page that uses the AppConverter class for pre-specified keys, and then using that to replace the `x:Static` with a binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppTitle},Converter={StaticResource ResourceRetriever}}" />
```

It works, but it's verbose and error prone compared to the WPF implementation (a lot of copying and pasting between pages, and even controls).

What is the current best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN How to: [Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know why that never came up in my searches. I must have been trying too hard. Thanks! That's awesome (though disappointing with the lack of support for the Application Bar) and incredibly similar to my approach, so it will be easy to swap in.